# Grabbing UISearchBar data - Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c

I've created a `UISearchBar` in one of my `ViewControllers` that contain different `containers` that link to other `ViewControllers`.  This `UISearchBar` is in the parent `ViewController`.  I am trying to grab the text that was entered in the search bar to be used to send to another `ViewController` The `UISearchBar` was created in `StoryBoard`.  I am using the following methods to try and receive information from the Search Bar:

```
- (void)searchBarTextDidBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
    NSLog(@"searching");
}

- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText {
    NSLog(@"Text change");

}

- (void)searchBarCancelButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
    NSLog(@"Cancel clicked");
}

- (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
    NSLog(@"Search Clicked");
}
```

Non of these functions above seem to run, I am not sure why.  Suggestions or thoughts?

UPDATE:

Here is what I am using to initiate the `Search Bar` now:

```
_aSearchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    [_aSearchBar sizeToFit];
    _aSearchBar.delegate = self;
    _aSearchBar.placeholder = @"Search YouTube...";
    _searchDC = [[UISearchDisplayController alloc] initWithSearchBar:_aSearchBar contentsController:self];

    [self performSelector:@selector(setSearchDisplayController:) withObject:_searchDC];

    _searchDC.delegate = self;
    _searchDC.searchResultsDataSource = self;
    _searchDC.searchResultsDelegate = self;
    [_aSearchBar release];
    NSLog(@"%@",[_searchDC.delegate class]); <------ this prints home which is the correct class
```

Now the only issue is, I can't see the search bar anymore?

Comment: Put breakpoint and check if one of these method gets called or not.If none of these method gets called, check if you have taken delegate of Serach bar in xib and defined your delegate in .h file.

Comment: @manthan I don't think I defined my Search Bar in my .h file.

Comment: If you have not defined your delegate in your .h file, then these methods won't get called man.

Comment: Sorry what I meant to say was I have the following: `@property (strong, nonatomic) UISearchBar *searchBar;` in my `.h`

Comment: yes but have u done lik this in your .h file? @interface ViewController : UIViewController<
UISearchBarDelegate
>

Comment: @manthan I do.  Still not running though.  For some reason I can't seem to connect the searchBar with the searchBar class in the storyboard.

Comment: Because you have not given the proper class in your file's owner in XIB. Click on files owner and check there is a name of your viewcontroller you are using for searchbar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the delegate methods are not being called it means that the UISearchBar doesn't know where to delegate the optional methods in `UISearchBarDelegate` protocol.

So the ViewController that implements these methods

```
- (void)searchBarTextDidBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
    NSLog(@"searching");
}

- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText {
    NSLog(@"Text change");

}

- (void)searchBarCancelButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
    NSLog(@"Cancel clicked");
}

- (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
    NSLog(@"Search Clicked");
}
```

must be set as the delegate of the UISearchBar. To make sure that the correct ViewController is set as the delegate of the `UISearchBar` I would print the

`[searchBar.delegate class]`

If this returns nil or some other class name then the one you expect, you will know where the problems comes from.

Hope this helps.

**UPDATE**

Ok, I just created a Single View Application and dragged a UISearchBar on the storyboard. Then I added an outlet for the UISearchBar called searchBar. Then I made the ViewController implement the UISearchBarDelegate protocol. Then in ViewDidLoad I set the `searchBar.delegate = self`. After I added all the delegate methods listed above everything worked... So the only thing that I can think of now is that the ViewController is not implementing the protocol

```
@interface ViewController () <UISearchBarDelegate>
```

Here's the ViewController source code:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController () <UISearchBarDelegate>

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISearchBar *searchBar;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    self.searchBar.delegate = self;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - UISearchBarDelegate
- (void)searchBarTextDidBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
    NSLog(@"searching");
}

- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText {
    NSLog(@"Text change");

}

- (void)searchBarCancelButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
    NSLog(@"Cancel clicked");
}

- (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
    NSLog(@"Search Clicked");
}
```

Comment: Okay that is perfect!  My issue was I was not connecting it to the outlet in storyboard